# assignment to ‘int’ from ‘int *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c, gcc

Estoy volviendo a intentar entender los punteros y demás y se salta el fallo indicado.

Os adjunto el código que estoy probando:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void matriz( int *hora, int *n)
{
    //size_t n = sizeof( &hora)/sizeof( &hora[0]);
    
    *( hora+ 0) = 12;
    *( hora+ 1) = 22;
    *( hora+ 2) = n;
    

}


int hora[ 3];
    
    
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    
    int n= (sizeof( hora)/sizeof( hora[ 0]));
    matriz( hora, n);

    printf( "Salida: %d -- %d -- %d\n", hora[0], hora[1], hora[2]);
    
}
```

Quiero disculparme ya que el fallo entiendo que es muy simple, pero hace mucho tiempo que no programa y estoy oxidado.

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta función recibe dos punteros:

```
void matriz( int *hora, int *n)
```

Pero a la hora de llamarla le pasas un puntero y un entero:

```
int hora[ 3];                               // <<--- Array -> Puntero
int n = (sizeof( hora)/sizeof( hora[ 0]));  // <<--- Entero
matriz( hora, n);
```

No se puede convertir alegremente un entero en un puntero y es justamente de lo que se está quejando el compilador.

El fallo se arregla haciendo que `n` deje de ser un puntero en `matriz`:

```
void matriz( int *hora, int n)
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!!!.